# wordpress main page is not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

i am getting "index of/" page instead of wordpress main page....

please check online at the link as follows : http://nzonesies.co.nz/shoppingcart/

please help me...i didn't move the wordpress or didn't delete anything..just did one edit in themes-functions.php file..

that was just to change the url for the cart button..first the main page was showing and products or other pages was not showing..but then the main page also stop to showing..

also checked permalinks and changed to default but still same...

Comment: thanks for your comments...i just want to know..what is the problem...

Comment: There is no index.html or index.php page.  Normally if such a page exist it will load automatically.  I only see an index123.php, try renaming that.

Comment: Follow this link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy wordpress uses a template hierarchy. There should be a index.php page which will get loaded . rename index123.php to index.php

Comment: ok..thanks...changed that..and it's working now...

Comment: just a little before it was the same as index123.php and the site was working...that's why i didn't take care for the index file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no index.html or index.php page. Normally if such a page exist it will load automatically. I only see an index123.php, try renaming that.